# Phpdoc for decorating class?

Tags: php, decorator

Im implementing a decorator pattern:

```
class DecorateMe
{
    public function a() { }
    public function b() { }
    public function c() { }
}

class Decorator
{
    /**
     * @var DecorateMe
     */
    private $beignDecorated;

    public function __construct(DecorateMe $beignDecorated)
    {
        $this->beignDecorated = $beignDecorated;
    }

    public function c() { }

    public function __call($name, $parameters)
    {
        return $this->beignDecorated->$name($parameters);
    }
}

$obj = new Decorator(new DecorateMe());
$obj->a();
$obj->b();
$obj->c();
```

all calls are valid, however IDE will offer `c()` method only. How to make it to offer all `a()`, `b()`, `c()` ?

Comment: AFAIK, IDEs do not support magic methods. Short of actually executing your code, there is no way for your IDE to know of the existence of `a()` and `b()` in the class `Decorator` other than trying to parse your `__call()` method and reverse-engineering what it does.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the class level `@method` php doc annotation.

```
/**
 * @method a()
 * @method b()
 * @method c();
 */
class Decorator { ... }
```

https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html

You could also automate this by using the `@mixin` annotation, if your IDE supports this (ie. PHPStorm does). Official, this annotation isn't supported by PhpDoc.

```
/**
 * @mixin DecorateMe
 */
class Decorator { ... }
```

Comment: isnt there any "automatic" way? Let me not update this list everytime I change something on my class

Comment: There's an `@mixin` - annotation in PHPStorm which provides this. This could just be written as `@mixin DecorateMe`

Comment: cool but it doesnt seem to be a regular solution. Its PhpStorm specific isnt it? Not general PhpDoc rule

Comment: No - @mixin isn't official documented in PhpDoc. It depends on your IDE, if this annotation is supported or not